# Why is "kicked ball" a violation in basketball?

Tags: rules, basketball

This may be opinion-based, but can anybody explain why "kicked ball", i.e. striking the ball with any part of the leg, is a violation in basketball? I've always thought it seemed like a fair play, not much different from striking the ball with your arms or hands. Kicked ball violation calls slow down the game, and at least in the [NBA](https://official.nba.com/rule-no-10-violations-and-penalties/), adds an additional element of judgement as to whether the kicking was intentional or not, although it always seems to be called regardless.

Comment: Striking the ball with your hands is the same violation, though.

Comment: @Joe How so? Striking it with your fist is a violation, but I don't think I've ever seen that called.

Comment: Your fist is your hand, no?  The point is that it's clearly not an attempt to control the ball - it's just being disruptive.

Comment: @Joe Sure, but any other contact with your hands is fine, so I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: Are you asking why you're not allowed to kick the ball? What reason is needed beyond, that's not the kind of game Basketball is (or they want it to be)?

Comment: @komodosp Like I said, it may be opinion-based, but it seems odd to slow down the game for a violation that doesn't seem to give an unfair advantage, and even if it was legal I don't think we'd see it happen significantly more.

Comment: I suppose technically any rule wouldn't give an unfair advantage as long as both teams are allowed do it. But (non-safety related) rules of games are usually guided by the type of game they want to play - e.g. why in Soccer are you not allowed to handle the ball, or in rugby to throw it forward. Allowing kicking would completely change the complexion of the game. "I don't think we'd see it happen". I think we would! e.g. Ball is bouncing low or rolling and your opponent is about to pick it up, I think taking a swing with your foot to boot it down the court or to a team-mate would happen a lot!

Comment: @komodosp Fair point although I think you could modify the rules to allow what currently occurs anyway (using your leg/foot to deflect a pass) without an infraction + shot clock reset, while still prohibiting the kinds of things you mentioned.

Comment: It's the nature of the game. Why is a handball in futbol/football/soccer a violation (even if accidental)? Calling it slows the game down and might even reward the penalized team if gives the defense a chance to get back when they weren't to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the basketball is intentionally hit by the leg/foot, a violation will be called. If a player uses a foot to prevent the ball from going out of bounds, it is a violation. If a cross-over hits the leg of an opponent intentionally, it is a violation. So, if the ball is blocked or hit intentionally by the leg or foot a violation might be called, no matter if you are defensive or offensive.

Not sure why more ball players do not use this to an advantage...it is much like being a goalie on the basketball court.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/25383)

Answer (score 0):

For a foot / leg infraction to be whistled voluntary is the first requirement. To be a foot violation it is necessary that whoever touches the ball with his leg does so as a result of a voluntary gesture. For example, if I am standing or making a legal defensive move, and you hit my leg trying to make a ground pass, there is no violation.

Once the voluntariness of the gesture has been clarified, then the concept of "advantage" can also be applied, although on the foot violation it is quite rare. For example: you pass the ball, I touch it with my foot but the ball still reaches your teammate unmarked under the basket. There would be a violation, but there is no booing so as not to dare an advantage to those who committed it.